# The below code is supposed to print 120.000000 for an input of 4 & 0. But it shows only 120. Why? and how to get desired output?

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float deg;
    int h,m;
    cin>>h>>m;     
    deg=h*30 - m*6; 
    cout<<deg;
    return 0;
}
```

**h and m are hours and mins**

**Question finds angle between the hour & min hand in deg.**

Comment: use `std::setprecision`

Comment: Can it not be done without it?

Answer (score 1):

cout<< fixed; is the answer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 float deg;
 int h,m;
 cin>>h>>m;     
 deg=h*30 - m*6;
 cout<<fixed;
 cout<<deg;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: WOW! That so worked!! Can you plssss tell me what exactly is "fixed"??

Comment: Numbers are always printed with a floating point and full precision.